# How does matplotlib calculate the 'gray' colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I call `plt.imshow(some_image, cmap="gray")`, how does `matplotlib` calculate the color map? I know how to apply custom color maps, specifically I am trying to figure out what the `gray` one does to the image data before displaying it.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormap-manipulation-py
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormapnorms-py

Comment: The real story is told in the links posted by Jody, in summary ① the values of `some_image` are normalized to the interval `[0, 1]` using by default a linear normalization, but you can use the `norm=...` keyword argument to specify a different normalization procedure ② the typical color map has 256 RGB entries and each point in the plot is assigned the color corresponding to its normalized value.